# Shell Script to download files

Tags: unix, shell

I am trying to write a unix shell script to download all the files in a directory posted on a website. How would I go about doing this? Thanks playas

Comment: Please be more specific. How does the website look like? Which directory are you talking about? Are the files included as `<a>` or are you referring to, let's say, an Apache index page?

Answer (score 5):

You could make use of `wget`'s flags:

```
--mirror

--no-parent
```

Answer (score 2):

[man wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
wget -r -np http://example.com/directory/to/files
```